# Sending file in a PUT request using HTML forms and Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, multipartform-data, forms, put

I am trying to send an image file to a backend server using a PUT request.

HTML:

```
<input type="file" name="myFile" id="profilePicInput">
```

Javacript:

```
const profileInput = document.getElementById('profilePicInput');
profileInput.addEventListener("change", handleFiles, false);

function handleFiles(){

    const formData = profileInput.files[0];

    $.ajax({
        url: '../uploadImage',    //my servlet url
        type: 'PUT',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        data: {
            data: formData
        }, 
        success: function () {
            console.log("profile pic updated!");
        }
    });
}
```

The problem I'm facing is, in my backend code, I'm receiving data that has a content-type of 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8', but what i need is 'multipart/form-data'.

I've tried two things that didn't work:

1. Using HTML forms

   ```
   <form id="profilePicForm" action="javascript:handleFiles()" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <input type="file" name="myFile" id="profilePicInput">
   </form>
   ```

   Javascript:

   ```
   const profileInput = document.getElementById('profilePicInput');
   profileInput.addEventListener("change", submitForm, false);

   function submitForm(){
      document.getElementById("profilePicForm").submit();
   }
   ```

   But still the content-type in the request header says 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8' in my PUT request.
2. Using FormData

   ```
   function handleFiles(){

       const blobFile = profileInput.files[0];
       let formData = new FormData();
       formData.append("fileToUpload", blobFile);


       $.ajax({
           url: '../uploadImage',    //my servlet url
           type: 'PUT',
           processData: false,
           contentType: false,
           data: {
               data: formData
           }, 
           success: function () {
               console.log("profile pic updated!");
           }
       });
   }
   ```

   Same problem. The content-type in the request header still says 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8' in my PUT request.

So my question is: how do you send a file with content-type=multipart/form-data through a PUT request?

---

**UPDATE**:

Solution:

HTML:

```
<input type="file" name="myFile" id="profilePicInput">
```

Javascript:

```
const profileInput = document.getElementById('profilePicInput');
profileInput.addEventListener("change", handleFiles, false);

function handleFiles(){

    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("fileToUpload", profileInput.files[0]);

    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('PUT', '../uploadImage');
    xhr.onload = () => {
        console.log("profile updated");
    };
    xhr.send(formData);

}
```

Comment: Where did you see `type: 'PUT'`? That would be `method: 'put'`, then if you do a PUT, why don't you send directly the File (using XHR that would be `var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); xhr.open('PUT', your_url); xhr.onload = callback; xhr.send(input.files[0]);`

Comment: This really helped, thanks! I used XHR like you recommended, coupled with HTML forms, and it worked! I didn't encounter the multipart boundary error which I have been struggling with. Thanks again!

Comment: @Kaiido — `method` and `alias` are aliases for each other in current jQuery. The value is case insensitive.

Comment: @Quentin my bad, didn't saw the `type` in the docs... But I didn't meant to imply it was case sensitive anyhow though.

Answer (score 2):

See MDN on [Uploading and Downloading Files](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/FileGuide/FileUpDown).

If you want to PUT *a file*, then you just need to put *the file* and not wrap it in a multipart/form-data container.

*Do not use FormData* which is designed to pulling in *all* the data from a form and not just sending a single file.

```
const fileToUpload = profileInput.files[0]);
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('PUT', '../uploadImage');
xhr.onload = () => {
    console.log("profile updated");
};
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", fileToUpload.type);
xhr.send(fileToUpload);
```

Comment: This looks like it would work, but unfortunate, my back-end code specifically requests for a multipart form, so I had to twist through a few loops.

Comment: @Sharon — Sounds like your backend code is misusing PUT horribly. I assume that when you later make a GET request to `../uploadImage` it doesn't send a multipart/form-data response to the browser?

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the documentation: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

It states that:

```
contentType: false,
```

will not send a content type, I would suggest this means the server recieving is then defaulting. Why not set the type here?

```
contentType: "multipart/form-data",
```

Comment: If I do that, I will get an error saying "org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found"

Comment: "will not send a content type" — No. It tells jQuery not to set a Content-Type and allows XMLHttpRequest to use its normal mechanism for setting it. If you pass XMLHttpRequest a FormData object, it will generate a `multipart/form-data` content type with the correct boundary parameter.

Comment: `contentType: "multipart/form-data",` —You're missing the boundry paramater which is **essential** for multipart/form-data messages.